# How can this be a null reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

```
Current.Images?.Count > 0 ? $"{Current.Images.Count} Image(s)" : "Enter Image";
```

Resharper thinks the Current.Images.Count could be a null reference.  It's good enough at figuring out if something can be null that this makes me wonder if I'm missing something.

My logic:  The only way the conditional can be true is if Images is not null and actually has at least one value.

Edit:  The problem is **not** with Current.  It can't be null at this point and Resharper knows that.

Comment: Could `Current` be null ?

Comment: I think Current is a class and Images a static list property. Based on this, Current couldn't be null?! But on the other side, there is no other option. ;)

Comment: @SeanStayn Why should it be static? If not, then `Current` could well be null.

Comment: Simple: Make `Current` null and see what happens. You are checking to make sure `Images` is not null, but you are not checking if `Current` is not null.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel can you show us the declaration of Current?

Comment: @DavidG I don't understand your comment. If Current is a class, how could Current be null? It's only an identifier. If you create an instance of the class Current, then it could be null. So my suggestion was, that Current is a class and not an object of each class. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SeanStayn `var Current = new Thing();` or `public Thing Current { get; set; }`

Comment: @DavidG Right, if Current is only an instance of some class, then it is possible. But my guess was that it is a class and not an object. Thank you for clearing this.

Comment: Why is everyone focusing on Current?  It's Images that can be null and is causing the warning I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465858) in R# 2017.2 and it is going to be fixed in upcoming R# 2017.2.1 bugfix update.

Answer (score 0):

If current is a varable, you should verify it isn't null:

```
((Current ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(Current)).Images?.Count > 0) 
    ? $"{Current.Images.Count} Image(s)" 
    : "Enter Image";
```

(This example has braces around the first line, for readability mostly. Because in some cases null coalescing expressions evaluate to null completely, and you save the reader of you code the trouble of figuring out if this is the case in this case. The decision whether to brace this way depends on your teams' code style preferences)

Also, spreading you code over multiple lines helps you figure out what part has the error.

If Current is a static class, then Resharper appears to be wrong. You can instruct resharper to ignore this instance (in your code) or to ignore every instance (in the resharper settings)

Comment: It's not actually causing an error, I'm asking why Resharper thinks it's dangerous.  Current can't be null and Resharper knows that.  Images **can** be null but how can it be null in the second reference?

Comment: I think RS is unable to correctly evaluate the expression.
Also, why can Images be null? (I always avoid collections that can be null. Often, null is incorrectly used instead of an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper marks your code as possible null reference exception, because you doesn't check Current.Images for null, **in your string literal**..

Your code:

```
Current.Images?.Count > 0 ? $"{Current.Images.Count} Image(s)" : "Enter Image";
```

Safe code:

```
Current.Images?.Count > 0 ? $"{Current.Images?.Count} Image(s)" : "Enter Image";
                                 missing ____^
```

Comment: That's how I handled it but I can't see any situation in which Current.Images is null at that point.  For the first test to evaluate non-zero there must actually be a collection with something in it.